# R: How do I make my package use another package?

Tags: r, package

This is very simple question. 
I am extending someone's package. It currently uses packages A, B and they are listed in the DESCRIPTION file.

If I need functions from package C - to add a package to the dependencies - do I just add the package in the DESCRIPTION file and that is all that is needed? Into what section - Depends or Imports? Are there more other steps to make? Do I need to use prefix C::functionInC() once my code needs to use a package C function?

Comment: The usual reference: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html Looks like Depends is discouraged in favor of Imports, glancing at the first section.

Comment: I had it in Imports and only after putting it into Depends it worked.

Comment: The fact that using Depends rather than Imports made it "work" may be misleading. Listing it in the Imports section in the description file only means it will be installed, not attached. Imports is still probably the best way to go, but you need to specify the imports in your NAMESPACE file as well, I think.

Comment: this is a basic/fundamental enough question that you prbly shld just [read a bit](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) on how to actually make packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**
Add C to Imports: and when using the C functions, use the double semicolon prefix.

**Longer context:**

The link below provides the following advice
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#imports

R functions

If you are using just a few functions from another package, my recommendation is to note the package name in the Imports: field of the DESCRIPTION file and call the function(s) explicitly using ::, e.g., pkg::fun().

If you are using functions repeatedly, you can avoid :: by importing the function with @importFrom pgk fun. This also has a small performance benefit, because :: adds approximately 5 µs to function evaluation time.

Alternatively, if you are repeatedly using many functions from another package, you can import all of them using @import package. This is the least recommended solution because it makes your code harder to read (you can’t tell where a function is coming from), and if you @import many packages, it increases the chance of conflicting function names.

Comment: what if the function from the imported package is the pipe (`%>%`) symbol? do you still prefix it somehow, or is it considered okay not to?

Comment: @stevec Try the usethis package. There is a specific function to import the pipe. usethis::use_pipe()